# How to highlight a column of a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do you dynamically highlight the clicked column of a WPF `ListView` with a grey colour?

Comment: You need to add more detail to this question so people can better understand what you are asking.  Maybe add some sample code to better illustrate what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ListView.Selection` change event with delegate handler like :

```
public delegate void SelectionChangedEventHandler(
      Object sender,
      SelectionChangedEventArgs e
  )
```

it will raise event when Item index changes, look for the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` it had two property,

`AddedItems` and `RemovedItems`, then change the `Background` of the `ListViewItem` in the collection of `AddedItems` & `RemovedItems`

Comment: I would like to make the entire COLUMN in Listview filled with grey or blue colour when user clicked on LISTVIEW HEADER. The purpose is to show which column is sorted. Any one knows how to set listview only one column background colour.